# removing dots and slashes regex - non relative

Tags: php, regex

how could I remove the trailing slashes and dots from a non root-relative path.

For instance, `../../../somefile/here/` (independently on how deep it is) so I just get `/somefile/here/`

Comment: That's useless question. it won't give you a real path anyway. What made you think you need such a replace? is it for the filesystem path or virtual web-server resource?

Comment: cause then one could do $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].newpath;

Comment: From where you get these paths with dots? it was hardcoded in your scripts and now you want to rewrite it to use with DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Why don't you want to replace it manually? Such a bulk replace may spoil some other addresses

Comment: The reason is cause the implementer might enter it as a non root-relative or root-relative, so the function will have to deal with either situation.

Comment: who is that implementer and why they have such an option? I've seen many PHP applications but never seen one you are talking about. a relative path is **not always** points to document root. Sometimes it just points to **relative** directory. I hope you do understand what are you doing.

Answer (score 8):

**No regex needed, rather use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/ltrim) with `/.`** . Like this:

```
 echo "/".ltrim("../../../somefile/here/", "/.");
```

This outputs:

```
 /somefile/here/
```

Comment: Note that the leading slash is significant — it invariably refers to the root directory.

Comment: Yes, that's why I appended it specially. User can remove it if needed and can still successfully strip all `/` and `.`

Comment: @Gumbo, that would display `/foo` stripping *slashes and dots* as required by the OP :)

Comment: @shamittomar: Gumbo has a good point actually. `/.foo` is not the same as `/foo`.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes I agree, they are definitely not same. But, even `../../../somefile/here/` and `/somefile/here/` are not same too (other than a case where it is in the directory which is in right position). So, I just answered the OP's question of what he wanted (*to strip `/` and `.`*) and left the reasoning and actual implementation and results to the OP and its web application.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [realpath()](http://www.php.net/realpath) function PHP provides. This requires the file to exist, however.

Comment: @Whoever downvoted, mind elaborating please? Reading the manual, this does what he wants, given the file exists.

Comment: AND it will do the right thing relative to the .. 's.  Something programmers OFTEN miss is a ".." on a *nix system might lead through a symlink, so the ..'s might actually move it to an entirely different part of the disk.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly:

```
$path = "/".str_replace("../","","../../../somefile/here/");
```

Comment: This would **fail** on `/../../../somefile/here/` and will return `//somefile/here`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php
echo "/".preg_replace('/\.\.\/+/',"","../../../somefile/here/")
?>
```

You can test it [here](http://codepad.org/PmkpobpJ).

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

```
<?php
$str = '../../../somefile/here/';
$str = preg_replace('~(?:\.\./)+~', '/', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\.*/)*(?<capturegroup>.*)`

The first group matches some number of dots followed by a slash, an unlimited number of times; the second group is the one you're interested in. This will strip your leading slash, so prepend a slash.

Beware that this is doing absolutely no verification that your leading string of slashes and periods isn't something patently stupid. However, it won't strip leading dots off your path, like the obvious `([./])*` pattern for the first group would; it finds the longest string of dots and slashes that ends with a slash, so it won't hurt your real path if it begins with a dot.

Be aware that the obvious "/." ltrim() strategy will strip leading dots from directory names, which is Bad if your first directory has one- entirely plausible, since leading dots are used for hidden directories.