# Php scandir limit access

Tags: php

I make a simple file manager script for my site.

In order to list all files and categories in a folder I use `scandir()` function. I have a variable that contains the basic path, like `$path = /var/www/mysite/uploads`. Then I have a function which takes GET variable containing additional path, like `/my/photos/` so I return the contents of `/var/www/mysite/uploads/my/photos`.

The problem is that if a user sends `../../../`, something like that, he'll go up on the directory tree and will be able to watch the whole system.

How can I restrict this? The only thing I've googled whas about `chroot`, but not sure if this is what I need

Comment: Don't let users have `../` in their input, strip it out if they have used it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php):

```
$storagePath = "/var/www/mysite/uploads";
$path = $storagePath . $userPath;

$path = realpath($path);
if(strpos($path, $storagePath) === 0){
   //Path is okay
   echo "Okay";
}
else {
   //User wants to gain access into a forbidden area.
   echo "Danger";
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://codepad.org/XLXsBHh7)

Explanation: The path provided by the user is contacted to the storage path. Then `realpath` is used to convert this path to an [absolute path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)). If the absolute path begins with the storage path everything is okay, otherwise not.

Of course it's also good to run the users provided path against a RegEx first so that you can make sure the path does only contains valid characters.

Comment: What do you think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661727/removing-dots-and-slashes-regex-non-relative about this? using ltrim? Actually I compose the resulting path like $path = $storagePath . $userPath; $userPath doesnt contain /var/www/whatever, it contains only part of path like /my/photos. So strpos won't return true anyway. But not sure if the solution with ltrim is enough

Comment: @Victor ltrim is good for sure, but I don't think it's enough. Why not just replace `$_GET["path"]` in my example above with `$storagePath . $userPath` (or `$path`). Then it will work with `strpos`, won't it?

Comment: If I have ?path=../../../../.., then the resulting path is /var/www/mysite/uploads/../../../../, strpos returns true as it finds /var/www/mysite/uploads in the beginning ?

Comment: @Victor No. `realpath` will convert path to `/` and then of course strpos will not return true.

Answer (score 0):

You always must verify the user inputs ! Do a regular expression to validate $_GET['path'].

Also, your server should be run by a user with very low privilege on your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The first question you must answer is why you are accepting from the user paths.

After this, if is really needed you must protect your input against absolute paths or the usage of `..` on it.

With something like

```
$project_path = realpath($project_path); 
$realpath = realpath($user_input); 
if (str_pos($realpath, $project_path) !== 0) {
    throw Exception('Security perimeter violation!');
}
```

Comment: I accept a path because if user wants to explore some folders he need to send folder name. And if folders are included in each other then it becomes something like '/my/photos/', so I give the user contents of $path.'/my/photos/'. I see that you and wumm both uses realpath, thanks for help, seems exactly what I need